# What are all of the possible IIS App Pool states?

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, automation, scripting

I am using with PowerShell's Invoke-Command with Get-WebAppPoolState on a remote IIS server.

Based on my testing, I know that "Started" and "Stopped" are two of the possible states.

Are there additional states that the app pool can be in? If so, is there a definitive list of all of the states?

The best documentation that I've been able to find is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/Get-WebAppPoolState).

Comment: For the old WebAdministration cmdlets, that link you pasted is probably the only. The new IISAdministration cmdlets built upon Microsoft.Web.Administration should expose the same values from this article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool.state?view=iis-dotnet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of them are exporting the **run-time state** of your application pool.

If you check the type of applicationpool.status property.

You will find it is objectStatus.
And all members of objectStatus are:
**Starting**, **Started**, **Stopping**, **Stopped**, and **Unknown**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.objectstate?view=iis-dotnet